# How to minimize and maximize text inside <td>

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two variables of long and short versions of the text. In table inside cell  if long version of text is not null there is should be a button(or other suitable element) in the end of short text. And when user press this button(or other suitable element) long version of text is shown instead short.

I tied to to this next way. There is part of code of my table:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="log in logs | orderBy:'-date'">
        <td>{{ log.date | date:"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.name }}</td>
        <td class="word-break">
            {{ isFullText ?  log.fullDescription : log.description  }} 
            <button ng-click="showDiffText()">{{ isFullText ? textButton[0] : textButton[1] }}</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And there is js function:

```
 $scope.isFullText = false;
 $scope.textButton = ['1', '2'];
 $scope.showDiffText = function ()
 {
      $scope.isFullText = !$scope.isFullText;
 }
```

Well, my way doesn't work at all. Any help, please?

Comment: check textButton variable what is contains - whether it is an array and has both indexes filled

Comment: what is `textButton` ? where does it come from ?

Comment: textButton is array with two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `isFullText` as you are using `ng-repeat` if you set it to `true` it will start showing full text for all the rows try attaching it at log lavel something like:-

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.logs=[{description :"sort",fullDescription:"long"},{description :"sort",fullDescription:"long"},{description :"sort"}]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="log in logs">
        <td class="word-break">
            {{log.showFull ? log.fullDescription : log.description}} 
            <button ng-if="log.fullDescription" ng-click="log.showFull = !log.showFull">Show{{log.showFull ? "Sort":"Long"}}</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```